# Format part of a file through uncrustify

Tags: uncrustify

I would like to format only a part of a sourcefile, like a function instead of the whole file.

This is needed because i can't format the old source completle. Only the newly added functions or changes in functions should be auto formated through uncrustify.

Is a selection based formating possible with uncrustify?

Maybe it is possible to do a automatic formatting of each function which is changed through a combination of git diff `--function-context` and a uncrustify call.

`git diff --function-context | uncrustify -xyc`

Answer (score 0):

You could go the other way. Save the output of git diff --function-context, then reformat the whole file, then revert the changes in lines which are not part of git diff --function-context.